# Invertible function with hard to find collisions in the Random Oracle Model

Tags: random-oracles

This question is inspired by [this tweet](https://twitter.com/VitalikButerin/status/1516317085290446848?s=20). I discussed this with some people at my institution when this came out and came to the conclusion that this was probably possible using lattice-based cryptography. I'd like to figure out if the task being described here can be carried out in the random oracle model.

To make the problem more explicit, here is what I am looking for:

A pair of algorithms $f_{\lambda, h}, f^{-1}_{\lambda, h}$ parametrized by a security parameter $\lambda$ and with oracle access to a random oracle $h : \{0,1\}^* \to \{0, 1\}$ such that:

- $f_{\lambda, h}$ maps $[0,2^\lambda)$ into $[0,2^\lambda-1)$
- $f^{-1}_{\lambda, h}$ maps $[0,2^\lambda-1)$ into $[0,2^\lambda)$
- Both algorithms require a number of oracle accesses polynomial in the security parameter.
- The task of finding a pair $x, y$ such that exactly one of $f_{\lambda, h}(x) = y$, $f^{-1}_{\lambda, h}(y)=x$ holds requires superpolynomially many oracle accesses in the security parameter on average.

Or otherwise, a proof that such a pair of algorithms is impossible to obtain.

See [here](https://ethresear.ch/t/a-solution-proposal-to-vitaliks-challenge-how-to-hide-pigeonhole-collisions-useful-for-verkle-trees-erasure-codes-many-ethereum-contrstuctions-etc/12466/6?u=boltonbailey) for my attempt at this and some discussion, I think some of my conclusions in that post are ultimately incorrect.